# SpecRun and TeamCity pass/fail integration

Tags: teamcity, specflow, specrun

We're using SpecRun as our test runner, whose logfile TeamCity consumes.

We've encountered a problem whereby a test in SpecRun will fail the first time (due to resources not warming up quickly enough), then pass the second retry (we have the SpecRun Default.srprofile setting to run up to three times)

However, TeamCity treats this as a failure after reading the log, when in fact it's really not.  Of course, we want to prevent any retries in SpecRun but in the meantime don't want to false-flag test runs in TeamCity.

Would anyone know of a way, either in SpecRun or TeamCity or a combination, to have a test that was retried successfully to be marked as a 'pass' in TC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an option to set build status to success using [Build Status Service message](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity#BuildScriptInteractionwithTeamCity-ReportingBuildStatus). When your test pass, report such message with status 'SUCCESS' in log output